# How to use ReteOO programmatically in Drools 7.5.0.Final

Tags: java-8, drools

I am trying to use ReteOO in Drools 7.5.0.Final and Java 8; however, the following code does not compile

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieBaseConfiguration kconfig = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();
kconfig.setOption(RuleEngineOption.RETEOO);
```

Also,  drools-reteoo-(version).jar is not included in the binary folder of Drools 7.5.0.Final distribution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The ReteOO isn't available anymore in Drools 7.x stream. PHREAK (as a ReteOO successor in Drools) is used as a default from 6.x series. If you need immediate or eager evaluation, you can use one of the propagation modes. See here in docs [1].

Regards,

Tibor

[1] https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.7.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_propagation_modes_2